# How do I tell doxygen to leave my XML comments alone?

Tags: xml, doxygen

I have that [fenced code block](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_fenced) with an XML fragment:

```c
/**
 * ~~~~~~{.xml}
 * <parent>
 *   <child></child>
 *   <!-- comment I want to see -->
 * </parent>
 * ~~~~~~
 */
```

The generated HTML documentation does no longer contain the comment:

[image]

How do I tell doxygen that it shall keep the comment also in the generated docs?

Comments in `C++` blocks are rendered properly, the issue is only with XML code.

Comment: maybe this Q&A could help

Comment: @gtosto which one?

Comment: lol sorry i forgot to paste the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129501/how-do-i-preserve-a-comment-in-an-example-in-doxygen)

Comment: @gtosto nope, doesnt help. C++ comments are working in my files too, the issue is XML

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What happens if you place a prototype under it (e.g. void fie(void); ), assuming it is in a file like aa.h ?

Comment: @albert it's in the doc head of a file. No prototype available. The docs get parsed and rendered correctly, the only issue is that the XML comment is swallowed away.

Comment: Which version of doxygen, as I see the XML comments.

Comment: @albert ah. Ok. I'll check when I'm back to work.